# Why changing colors in C++ console application by system("color YX") is not the best solution?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I read somewhere, (knowing that both ways will work only for windows) that using system is not the best solution.

Why

```
#include<windows.h>
...
HANDLE hOut;
hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hOut,BACKGROUND_RED);
```

is better?

What I know, that system("color YX") change colors of entire console. However I assume, that there is a way to do it by "switching on and off" some colors during printing texts.

Is it true that system(command) will use additional layer during communication with system/console, what could be avoid using second method?

Is there any other reason why should I use second method?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other reason why should I use second method?

`system(command)` will compile on any system, no matter what 'command' is.  Using the windows functions ensures that your code will only compile on the system on which it actually works.  Down the line, if you ever want to port this code, you will get a clear compiler error, so you'll spend less time tracking down the reason your code doesn't work.

Comment: +1 It's also easy to create a wrapper for e.g OS X or Unix to provide equivalent functionality to the `SetConsoleTextAttribute` function, whereas those systems don't have a `color` command on them.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization wise, the system(command) call creates a separate process, pass the argument "color XY" and then that process searches for the command "color" and executes it.

Note that since color is a console internal command its execution is pretty much immediate. However, for commands that are not internal, it would create yet another process and execute that command in that separate process.

That means create 2 processes which is very slow (2Mb of stack for each, full process information such as IP address, registers, stdin/stdout/stderr, ...)